# Directed trees and the order/score of each node in the tree

Tags: graphs, hamiltonian-path, spanning-trees

Suppose we have a directed tree as follows:

[image]

The information regarding the edges are also given to us as a list
like edge_info = [ (a,c) , (a,b) , (b,d) , (b,e) , (b,f) ]

I am trying to find a way to assign a number to each node as follows:

- a --> 0
- b ---> 1
- d, e, f ---> 2
- c---> 1

Like the distance from the original node a
I need to do it without solving any optimization model just by normal operations / algorithm (sorting, reordering)

It should be done no matter the order of edge information is given to us in edge_info list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the set of nodes. The following procedure should require $O(\vert N \vert^3)$ time (I think).

Start by defining a set $P_n=\emptyset$ for all $n\in N.$ Scan the list of arcs, and for each arc $(i,j)$ add $i$ to $P_j.$ Once done, $P_j$ contains the list of all immediate predecessors of node $j.$

Now set $d=0$ ($d$ will index the depth in the graph) and set $L_d=\emptyset$ ($L_d$ will be the set of nodes at depth $d$). For every $n\in N,$ add $n$ to $L_d$ if and only if $P_n=\emptyset.$ Once that scan is done, replace $N$ with $N\backslash L_d$ and for each remaining $n\in N$ replace $P_n$ with $P_n \backslash L_d.$ Increment $d$ by one and repeat until $N$ is empty.

Note: This should work for any layered digraph. For a directed tree, $\vert P_n \vert$ will never exceed 1.

Comment: Thanks, Does it also work for disconnected graphs (two islands, two disconnected trees) ?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow either fdepth-first or breadth-first  traversal while using dynamic programming. You can define $d(s,v,z)=$ "depth(s), vector(v), distance from root " where vector is direction of child nodes i, like maybe an order [1,2,3,..] as they (set of i) appear in edge list, L for a node j.

$ s=0; v=0$
$f(s,a)= d(s,v,0)$
$j= a$

$\forall i \in  L(j)$: For-loop
$z[i]= edge(j,i)$
$s[i]= 1$
$f(s,i) = d(s[i]+s[j],v,z[i]+z[j])$
$ v=v+1$

$ j= L(0)$ : move to first child node of parent node, j and repeat.
$s=s+1$: update stage/depth\

till $s \ \exists$

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use python to draw the decision tree as shown above, you can use ***[Networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html)*** package to labeling or scoring the tree by using the [relabel_nodes()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/relabel.html#relabel_nodes) method as follows:

**The original tree:**

[image]

**The labeled tree:**

[image]

you can use any labale or score to draw the graph. I hope it helps.